# UISearchBar implementation Like Instagram IOS7

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar, instagram

Hello i am trying to implement a uitabbarview defined only for search. Ideally i want to implement the exact same style that instagram does Not the suggestions but the actual search bar and the tab controls to switch between the users and hashtags. [image] I've been researching online and haven't found anyone with my exact problem. Any help would be appreciated. Disregard the device and all and  just focus on the searchable with the two segmented tabs. i want something exactly like this and ill handle all the search and results etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to find info on is the `UISearchBar` and especially the `UISearchBar` delegate method called `shouldChangeTextInRange`

Find out more about `UISearchBar` and its delegate methods [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Helpful tutorial [here](http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/) (Filters the `UItableView` result as you type)